# Slower Rendering in newest daily build 2.79.4 vs. 2.79

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance

I've installed version 2.79.4 and it is a bit slower than 2.79. I render with GPU 980TI, and the same scene with the same settings (opened and rendered without any changes).

- **Older** - 1000 samples, denoiser, 2K res - **3:45min**
- **Newer** - 1000 samples, denoiser, 2K res - **4:00min**

Am i missing something? Or should i turn on or off something? 
It's not a big deal, but 15sec is about 6% slower. 
Just asking

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

With the amount of changes that happened between versions, I am not surprised at the performance difference.

Blender 2.79a also switched from CUDA 8 to CUDA 9, which Could be slightly slower on older generation hardware.